# U.S. motto change from "E Pluribus Unum" to "In God We Trust"

Tags: united-states, religion, reference, us-constitution

[*Latin for Dummies*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9834) p. 310 says:

> As a result of the Communist scare of the 1950s, U.S. President Dwight D. Eisenhower and the U.S. Congress changed the U.S. motto to *In God We Trust*. But before the 1950s, the U.S. Motto had been the Latin phrase ***e pluribus unum*** (*one, out of many*).

What exactly was the bill and where can I find the full text for it?

Answer (score 1):

[H.J.Res.396](https://www.congress.gov/bill/84th-congress/house-joint-resolution/396/text) - Joint resolution to establish a national motto of the United States, 84<sup>th</sup> Congress (1955-1956)
<sub>Introduced Date:   07/21/1955
Latest Action:    07/30/1956 Became [Public Law No. 84-851](https://www.congress.gov/bill/84th-congress/house-joint-resolution/396/text)</sub>

> JOINT RESOLUTION
>
> To establish a national motto of the United States.
>
> *Resolved by the Senate and House of Representatives of the United
> States of America in Congress assembled*, That the national motto of
> the United States is hereby declared to be “In God we trust.”
>
> Approved July 30, 1956.